# Triangles seem to be fighting/jumping while rendering in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm having a problem while rendering a 3d model in OpenGL. I am able to render it, but when it does the triangles look like they're fighting to be on top. I'm not really sure why this would be happening.
Here's a video of what I'm talking about: [Jittery Triangles.](http://youtu.be/cgB-hdx0VvA) I'm using immediate mode in this video, but it was doing the same thing using VBOs.

*EDIT: Well Thanks Tim! I for some reason had my near plane set to 0.00001 and changing it to 0.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: How about a code sample? Whats your near/far plane setup like?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892489/how-to-get-the-rid-of-the-z-fighting-problem-in-opengl

Comment: why would the near plane set too close cause problems?

Comment: @MichaelDorst: It's probably due to the separation between the near and far rather than the absolute distance of the near plane. When your near and far planes are very far (keeping in mind the logarithmic precision of floats) the rounding of floats causes two nearby Z-values to compare differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as z-fighting and it occurs when precision is lost in the z-buffer. The usual causes are:

1. objects very far away from the camera
2. objects very close together or in exactly the same spot
3. A far clipping plane that's very far away
4. Matrix math inaccuracies

I'd say that #3 is the most likely cause of your problems. You always have to keep an eye out for floating point errors!

#4 is another possible problem, but it usually only crops up if you have a camera transformation very far from the origin, and can be solved by using matrices of doubles and converting them to floats just before passing them to the gpu.

Here is a good article on [projection matrix Z-buffer math](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html).